# gulp-util now included in npm install of gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

ok, so I didn't find my answer in the already asked questions.  I recently had to reload my node to include trying to reload all the globally loaded 'things' (that I could remember).

Back when I was learning "Gulp", I remember having to do a separate install for gulp-util.  But when I looked in the node > node_modules folder, I see where gulp-util was already loaded as a sub module of gulp.  This was also a duplicated and exact version as to my separate install of gulp-util.

So does gulp (npm install -g gulp), now come with gulp-util as a part of its install process. So doing a separate install of gulp-util is pointless and overkill??   Or do I still need to do it???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you still need.

The fact that `gulp-util` is a submodule (along with any other) of `gulp` just means that `gulp` uses it, but doesn't mean that you don't need to include it.

If you want to get `gulp-util` from `gulp` you can do something like it:

```
var gutil = require('gulp/node_modules/gulp-util')
```

But, I strongly advise you not to.

Anyway, `gulp` is a build tool, overkill shouldn't be a concern here since you won't ship it or its rendundant submodules for the client.

Comment: Rigotti,  Thank you for the information.  Since I am 'pushing the envelope' here in the office (day job) and others will follow in my footsteps, I wanted to set a standard or atleast adhere to best practices as much as possible.